# what does amp draw @12vdc mean?

Tags: power-supply

what does amp draw @12vdc mean? i have a 12v winch with the max saying 2500 lbs amp draw is 132 @12vdc / i want to plug into a wall 110 / so what converter do i need / thank you

http://www.harborfreight.com/2500-lb-atvutility-electric-winch-with-wireless-remote-control-61297.html

thats the on i have

i am a novice here so please lamens terms please

Answer (score 3):

That means that the winch will require 132 amps at 12 volts DC when pulling its rated load.  It is intended to be used on a car, truck, or ATV, and be connected to the vehicle's battery.

To operate it from 120V AC, you would need an AC power supply capable of providing 132 amps at 12 volts DC.

If you need a winch to operate from 120 V AC, you should look for one intended for that application.

Comment: so is there a ac power supply that would do that

Comment: A 130 amp power supply will be expensive.  I'd probably use a car battery and a suitable battery charger.  As I said, if you intend to operate the winch from 120 VAC, you should look fro a winch intended for that 120V operation.

Comment: i just need an electric wireless hoist small in size that can pick up 1000 lbs / just cant find one and the battery thing is not going to happen due to how i have to use it / thanks for helping out everybody / i see people wire up 12v wireless remotes to a an electric hoist but im not well versed in that

Comment: @nickmelone: just to add a bit to your problem - there is a difference between a winch and a hoist.  A hoist is intended to lift things, and, as such, should hold the position when power is removed.  A winch is intended to pull horizontally, and need not hold position if power is removed. You can pull cable off an unpowerd winch, but not off an unpowered hoist.  Be sure that whatever you get is suitable for your application.  Whether you have wired or wireless control is a separate matter.